# .htaccess redirect all POST request with data to a file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a `.htaccess` file in a subfolder (www.domain.com/API/) and I need to redirect all POST requests of this subfolder into a file in a subfolder (www.domain.com/API/Sub/manager.php)

I must say all POST requests will have data (2-10 parameters) and all data most be redirect too.

I have read some posts and pages but they cannot solve my situation.

I have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net/API/Sub/manager.php [QSA,L]
```

However, I got something like:

> 302 Found --> The document has moved (link to
>   ww.domain.com/API/Sub/manager.php)

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

P.S.
These are some pages I looked into:

[Redirect POST htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638678/redirect-post-htaccess)

[Seems like POST values are lost when .htaccess RewriteRule used. GET values are OK. How to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826861/seems-like-post-values-are-lost-when-htaccess-rewriterule-used-get-values-are)

[.htaccess redirect all sub-directories to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060355/htaccess-redirect-all-sub-directories-to-file)

Comment: Thanks @thickguru I am pretty new on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the wrong status code.  In a nutshell, the 302 code is not requesting that the browser retransmit all data (the POST request); you need to use the 307 code instead.

To do this under Apache, update that last rule to end with

> [QSA,L,R=307]

If you are *only* interested in the POST data, you don't even need the QSA flag.

For the gory details, you can see the entire list of HTTP status codes and their meanings [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).  The reason the 302 code is not functioning the way you want it to is explicitly called out in on the protocols page as follows (emphasis mine)

> Note: RFC 1945 and RFC 2068 specify that the client is not allowed
>   to change the method on the redirected request.  However, most
>   existing user agent implementations treat 302 as if it were a 303
>   response, **performing a GET on the Location field-value regardless
>   of the original request method**. The status codes 303 and 307 have
>   been added for servers that wish to make unambiguously clear which
>   kind of reaction is expected of the client.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I implemented your code but know I do not get any response, I got:

Comment: "The document has moved here"

Any other suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, I had an issue in one of my files. 307 was what I was looking for. Thanks